# What are tab-icons called and how can I extract this one in order to do a reverse image search?

Tags: browser, browser-tabs

Sorry if this is not fully on-topic, I am not sure where the best place to post this is.

I noticed that these two seemingly unrelated websites have seemingly identical "icons" on their tabs in my browser.

1. What is the proper name for these "icons" in developer-speak?
2. Besides a screen shot, how can I extract these "icons" from the web page in order to do some kind of reverse image search on it?

URLs viewed in these two tabs (Chrome Incognito, MacOS)

- Left: [POC optical fiber manufacturing module arrives at International Space Station](https://www.laserfocusworld.com/articles/2019/04/poc-optical-fiber-manufacturing-module-arrives-at-international-space-station.html)
- Right: [SfePy: Notes on Multi-platform Python Distributions](http://sfepy.org/doc-devel/installation.html#id5)

[image]

Comment: They're favicon.ico or shortcut icon, but your browser likely has a default when the website doesn't have a favicon in the root. If you instead the <head> section of this page, it'll show "shortcut icon" as https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/superuser/img/favicon.ico?v=29b26120d2c5

Comment: @spikey_richie - I was about to write that as an answer but you beat me to it in a comment. Feel free to post that as a proper answer and you have my upvote.

Comment: An answer would be most appreciated, as I can't yet understand the brief comment. Please feel free to edit/improve/enhance the question if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: The comment is now an answer, but what more do you expect to see?

Comment: You could probably quote a block or two from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) wikipedia post and cite it as source, just to have a little bit more of a robust answer. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Good point @n8te.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're called favicon.ico or "shortcut icon", but your browser likely has a default when the website doesn't have a favicon in the root. If you inspect the  section of this page, it'll show "shortcut icon" as `cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/superuser/img/favicon.ico?v=29b26120d2c5`

For the 2 websites you linked, if there's no favicon.ico in the website root, I believe you're going to be stuck with those default icons.

For more information on favicons, you can refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) wikipedia page.

Comment: Okay I understand. Whatever that image is, it's either stored by my browser or specified in some link in my browser, and so there's no point in searching for the image.

Comment: I've just seen this favicon on a third site, never seen it before today. I think it might have been just recently pushed out into Chrome by google.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-favicon-changer/acmfnomgphggonodopogfbmkneepfgnh

Comment: Yes it seems to be a new default https://i.stack.imgur.com/89fhs.png

Comment: In addition to the browsers default favicons, you also often see unrelated sites with the same default icons provided by webservers, web frameworks, CMS or hosting providers.

Comment: "no favicon.ico in the website root" - root is the default location for the icon, but your SuperUser example already shows that a site may override that default location. The browser icon only shows up if there's neither a icon in the website root nor a specific override.